# What is the simplest way to draw in Java?

Tags: java, swing, paint

What is the simplest way to draw in Java?

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Canvas
{
    private JFrame frame;    
    private Graphics2D graphic;
    private JPanel canvas;

    public Canvas()
    {
        frame = new JFrame("A title");
        canvas = new JPanel();
        frame.setContentPane(canvas);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        BufferedImage offImg = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Grapics2D g2 = offImg.createGraphics();
        g2.setColor(new Color(255,0,0));
        g2.fillRect(10,10,200,50);
    }
}
```

This doesn't work and I have no idea how to get anything to appear.

Comment: I wish everybody would stop recommending to override paint(). Custom painting in Swing is done by overriding paintComponent(). Please read the Swing tutorial on Custom Painting (http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Easiest way:

```
public class Canvas extends JPanel {

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        // painting code goes here.
    }
}
```

You simply need to extend `JPanel` and override the  `paintComponent` method of the panel.

I'd like to reiterate that you should **not** be overriding the `paint` method.

Here is a very minimalistic example that works.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    JPanel p = new JPanel() {
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.drawLine(0, 0, 100, 100);
        }
    };
    f.add(p);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: Any specific reason not to override paint?

Comment: @Neo, it has to do with the paint cycle.  If you override `paint` you can screw with the paint cycle of the component.

Comment: @Neo, here is an example from Sun that overrides `paintComponent` - http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/swing2d/index.html

Comment: @Neo overriding paint usually make it forget about it's components that need to be painted as well. It works for simple, naive programs, but as you get more complicated you're going to find your underlying stuff stops being painted and it won't make any sense.

Comment: For custom painting, there is little if any functionality that JPanel can do that JComponent cannot.  Unless some extra JPanel method is required, it would make sense to use JComponent instead.

Comment: @Andrew, I have never used a `JComponent` for custom painting.  Does it have any benefits over using a `JPanel`?

Comment: What do you pass to paintComponent to make it draw something on screen?

Comment: @Neo, you don't ever call `paintComponent`.  You simply override it in the JComponent and provide your custom drawing code there.

Comment: @jjnguym so how does it run? I'm still not seeing anything when I run it. Just a frame shrunk as small as it can go.

Comment: @Neo, you have to resize the frame.  Or, call `f.setSize(100,100);` before making the frame visible.  The call to `f.visible(true)` is the line that essentially 'runs' it.

Answer (score 1):

```
// No. 1
// Create a graphics context on the buffered image
Graphics2D g2d = bimage.createGraphics();

// Draw on the buffered image
g2d.setColor(Color.red);
g2d.fill(new Ellipse2D.Float(0, 0, 200, 100));
g2d.dispose();

// No.2
// In case the buffered image supports transparency

g2d = bimage.createGraphics();

// Transparency is created on all the filled pixels
Color transparent = new Color(0, 0, 0, 0);
g2d.setColor(transparent);
g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.Src);
g2d.fill(new Rectangle2D.Float(20, 20, 100, 20));
g2d.dispose();
```

Answer (score 0):

To make something appear in paint(Graphics g) you need to call the drawing methods (like fillRect) on that Graphics. You are creating a bitmap and then drawing to the bitmap, not the screen.

```
public void paint(Graphics g){
    g.setColor(new Color(255,0,0));
    g.fillRect(10,10,200,50);
}
```

Comment: This is Swing, not AWT, you should be overriding paintComponent not paint.

Answer (score 0):

jjnguy already wrote how to do it right ... but here why it does not work in your example:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Canvas
```

Here you have a class which does not relate in any way to Swing or AWT.
(By the way, you may want to select another name to avoid confusion with `java.awt.Canvas`.)

```
{
    private JFrame frame;    
    private Graphics2D graphic;
    private JPanel canvas;

    public Canvas()
    {
        frame = new JFrame("A title");
        canvas = new JPanel();
        frame.setContentPane(canvas);
```

Here you are creating a new JPanel (for confusion also named `canvas`), and add it to the frame.
Is is this panel's `paint` and `paintComponent` methods which are called when the system shows your frame.

```
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        BufferedImage offImg = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Grapics2D g2 = offImg.createGraphics();
        g2.setColor(new Color(255,0,0));
        g2.fillRect(10,10,200,50);
    }
```

This paint method is never used at all (since it is not part of a component), and if it would be called, then you are only painting to some BufferedImage, not to the screen.

```
}
```