# How to draw a line in java?

Tags: java, graphics2d

I want to draw a line in java in eclipse. I made this code but I am getting error in line : `paint2d.add(paintComponent());`

```
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Game extends JPanel {

    public void paintComponent (Graphics2D g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.drawLine(30, 40, 80, 100);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(400, 420);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Game paint2d = new Game();
        paint2d.add(paintComponent()); // The method paintComponent(Graphics2D) in the type Game is not applicable for the arguments ()
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

How to fix that error?

Is my code suitable for the purpose of drawing a line?

Thanks.

Comment: The method `paintComponent` returns void. The painting does not have to be called explicitly. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5801734/how-to-draw-lines-in-java.

Comment: `paintComponent` methods return type is `void`....I think that is why the error.

Comment: Don't call paintComponent yourself. Add your Game to the frame, and it will be called automatically.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/5303712/14955

Comment: ok .. I tried `paint2d.add(frame);`
and  `frame.add(Game);` but they did not work ..thanks

Comment: `frame.add(paint2d)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to draw lines in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5801734/how-to-draw-lines-in-java)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not overriding the method correctly. The argument to `paintComponent` is of type `Graphics`, not `Graphics2D`, but you can cast to `Graphics2D`. Also you need to add the `Game` panel to the frame as a content pane:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Game extends JPanel
{

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2.drawLine(30, 40, 80, 100);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(400, 420);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Game game = new Game();
        frame.setContentPane(game);

        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.invalidate();
    }

}
```

Comment: God bless you , it works ... but why it does not work if I have  `public void paintComponent(Graphics2D g)` instead of `public void paintComponent(Graphics g)`

Comment: See java api for help.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintComponent-java.awt.Graphics-

Comment: Your `Game` class extends the `JPanel` class. The `JPanel` already defines a method called `paintComponent`. In your implementation, you redefine this method (override it). The compiler does only understand this mechanism, if your new method declaration matches the method of `JPanel` exactly. If you specify the `Graphics2D` as the parameter to the method, the compiler does not understand the overriding and your method won't be called at all, but the original method from the `JPanel` will run.

Answer (score 0):

There are two errors in your code/approach:

1. The method **paintComponent** has a **Graphics** as parameter, not a **Graphics2D**.
2. Game is a JPanel and must be added into the JFrame to be shown.

The source code below solves the problems.

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Game extends JPanel {

    public void paintComponent (Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.drawLine(30, 40, 80, 100);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(400, 420);

        // Adds Game panel into JFrame
        frame.add(new Game());

        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```